# Alias for a lambda

Tags: c++, c++11

The ISO C++ FAQ (https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-language-templates, "Template aliases") quotes the following example:

```
using P = [](double)->void; // using plus suffix return type
```

I get an error trying to compile this with g++ -std=c++11:

```
error: expected type-specifier before ‘[’ token
```

What should the correct syntax be? If I do

```
auto p = [](double)->void {};
```

p gets deduced to be either `<lambda(double)>` or `main()::<lambda(double)>`, depending on the scope. However, I can't then do

```
using P = <lambda(double)>;
```

as that also gives an error:

```
expected type-specifier before ‘<’ token
```

Comment: Mmmmh, that's broken.

Comment: Why do you need to alias for a lambda? What about a function pointer: using FunctionPtr = void (*)(double);

Comment: Not an answer, but `using P = std::function<void(double)>;` would probably work for you, as the lambda is convertible to the std::function.

Comment: @Dana Yan: I was just querying whether the FAQ is actually correct - it seems not.

Comment: @SirVisto A lambda is [an unnamed function object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). The answer of Rakete1111 is pretty good.

Answer (score 6):

It's been fixed! The updated entry reads:

```
using P = auto (*)(double)->void;
```

---

According to [[expr.prim.lambda]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.lambda), a lambda expression is:

> ```
> lambda-expression:
>     lambda-introducer lambda-declarator[opt] compound-statement
>     lambda-introducer < template-parameter-list > lambda-declarator[opt] compound-statement
> ```

The *compound-statement* is not optional, and so `[](double)->void` is not a valid lambda expression.

`[](double)->void {}` is not a type, and `decltype([](double)->void {})` is ill-formed. There is no easy way to get the type of a lambda directly. You can always use a workaround like

```
auto p = [](double) -> void {};
using P = decltype(p);
```

But I'd recommend just sticking with function pointers or `std::function`, depending on your use case, because each lambda has a different type.

`<lambda(double)>` is not a type, nor an object. It's just a way for your compiler to refer to a specific lambda, it's not valid C++ whatsoever.